# scss nesting syntax: nest with parent adjoin class

Tags: css, sass

I want to output:
`.selector.another-selector .selector__block{some declaration}`
but i want to nest it:
I am using & at the end so I can nest it under `__block`,
but how can I make it adjoin class with `.selector`?
code example:

```
.selector{
  &__block{
  // i want to put my .another-selector declaration here
  .another-selector &{ 
    //syntax issue
    //need to make it .selector.another-selector .selector__block
  }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you nest your selector, then it has to be in the .selector__block context (`&`).

You have 2 solutions here :

You can repeat the first selector, as such:

```
.selector {
  &__block {
      ...
      .another-selector.selector & { 
          // Here `&` means  `.selector__block`
      }
  }
}
```

You can nest differently:

```
.selector {
  &__block {
    ...
  }
  &.another-selector &__block { 
     // Here `&` means  `.selector`
  }
}
```

Maybe the second solution is better since it respects the [inception rule](http://thesassway.com/beginner/the-inception-rule) and is less dependent of the DOM structure.

BTW, you can also try https://www.sassmeister.com/ to play with your selectors

Comment: For some reason this got down voted??? I agree with Tibo  (solution 2) -  don't overcomplicate things

Comment: nesting BEM is usually overcomplicating things. How is solution two a good solution as you have to declare `&.another-selector &__block`, not that simple if you have a real project that you gone maintain and not a hello world?

Comment: this is a maintenance mission. cannot re-write the code.
just wanted to organize it. 
Anyway this solution is ok, after some thinking i agree to much nesting here is bad.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you don't nest BEM at all. Just go with plain declarations for two valid reasons.

1) error tracking nested BEM is hard, let say you get a class from devtools that is `.hero__heading`. That will not match anything in your code when doing a search. Now the example above is not that hard to figure out anyway but inheriting a project with nested structure is a pain. **I suggest reading [Harry Roberts article on code smells in css](https://csswizardry.com/2017/02/code-smells-in-css-revisited/)**

2) nesting like this will often complicate when wanting to override with other classes like in your case.

Consider this code:

```
.selector {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.selector__block {
  color: lightblue;

  .another-selector & {
    color: lightcoral;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dejan.S I'm not a big fan of BEM (but that's another rant ;-). If however you are using BEM I think nesting will help to illustrate the hierarchy and what to expect

SCSS:

```
.selector {
    //  selector styles
    color: red;

    //  default selector block style 
    &__block { color: green; }

    //  selector variant selector block styles 
    &.foo &__block { color: blue;   }
    &.bar &__block { color: yellow; }
}
```

CSS Output:

```
.selector { color: red; }
.selector__block { color: green; }
.selector.foo .selector__block { color: blue; }
.selector.bar .selector__block { color: yellow; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="selector">
    Selector  <!-- red -->
</div> 
<div class="selector">
    Selector  <!-- red -->
    <div class="selector__block">
        Selector Block  <!-- green -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="selector foo">
    Selector  <!-- red -->
    <div class="selector__block">
        Selector Foo Block   <!-- blue -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="selector bar">
    Selector  <!-- red -->
    <div class="selector__block">
        Selector Bar Block  <!-- yellow --> 
    </div>
</div>
```